# Example getting started with scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would need help with getting started with scikit-learn.
A very simple solution as a starting point would help a lot.
Pointing me to an example with a similar problem would also help.

I have a textfile with following content (history.txt)

```
Id=101;Username=john;Date=1475359200;Announcement=111;Result=50;Title=blub;MassRequest=111;VolumeRequest=10
Id=104;Username=john;Date=1475359900;Announcement=40;Result=23;Title=blah;MassRequest=300;VolumeRequest=50
Id=222;Username=dave;Date=1475399200;Announcement=600;Result=420;Title=foo;MassRequest=40;VolumeRequest=20
Id=301;Username=john;Date=1475559200;Announcement=300;Result=150;Title=bar;MassRequest=10;VolumeRequest=33
Id=407;Username=dave;Date=1475659200;Announcement=200;Result=180;Title=blah-foo;MassRequest=90;VolumeRequest=55
```

After reading this file into a Pandas DataFrame, i would like to train scikit.
With a new input "new_announce" i want to receive a value for a possible "Result".

```
import pandas as pd

history = []
f = open("history.txt",'r')
for line in f.read().strip().split('\n'):
    dummy = {}
    for data in line.split(';'):
        if data:
            (key,value) = data.split('=')
            dummy[key] = value
    history.append(dummy)

#df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(history)
df = pd.DataFrame(history)

#Train here scikit-learn

new_announce ={'Id': '507',
              'Username': 'dave',
              'MassRequest': '10',
              'Announcement': '333',
              'Title': 'foobar',
              'MassRequest': '10',
              'VolumeRequest': '55'}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented a very basic example using pandas and sclearn MultinomialNB.

A example of it is here.

```
import pandas as pd
from util import Util
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# Load CSVs into panda dataframes
u=Util()
reviews_df = u.getCommentsDf()

# Divide data into train and test dataset
split= int(round(0.7 * len(reviews_df)))
train =reviews_df[:split]
test=reviews_df[split:]

print ("Training data ")
print(train.groupby('suspended').size())
print ("Testing data " )
print(test.groupby('suspended').size())

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')

# Learn the vocabulary dictionary and return term-document matrix
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(train['body'].values.astype('U'))
y = train['suspended']

clf =MultinomialNB()
# Fit Naive Bayes classifier according to X, y
clf.fit(X,y)


xTest=vectorizer.transform(test['body'].values.astype('U'))
# Perform classification on an array of test vectors X
pred = clf.predict(xTest)

# generate report
trueValue= test['suspended']


print 'Accuracy Score \t '+ str(accuracy_score(trueValue, pred, normalize=False))
```

You can use other tools and library to extract features and play around.

Also some good references apart from [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) are [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiKMIuYidY0) and [here](https://youtu.be/URTZ2jKCgBc?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDd0flgGphKCej-9jp-QdzZ3).

If you are looking for something specific, do post a question.

Comment: Could you provide a sample a few line of your csv file?

Comment: id       timestamp   body  suspended
0        210876912  (text)   0
1        225412275  (text)   0